# How to insert Gujarati in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

How can insert Gujarati language in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

I have tried to insert Gujarati and use `nvarchar` datatype but it's not working

Answer (score 5):

The most common problem that I see when people aren't getting the outcome they want when inserting into an `nvarchar` column is that they aren't putting `N` in front of their string literal values (`N` is National Character Set).

If you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    TestID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TestValue nvarchar(100)
);
```

Here's a Chinese example that won't work (because of multi-byte string values):

```
INSERT dbo.Test (TestValue) VALUES ('Hello 你好');
```

With just single quotes, it's just an ASCII string. What would work is:

```
INSERT dbo.Test (TestValue) VALUES (N'Hello 你好');
```

I'm guessing your issue might be similar for Gujarati.

Comment: "With just single quotes, it's just an ASCII string": Not ASCII, but so-called ANSI. N'ice' answer, though.

Comment: True. For most people it ends up ASCII but it does include whatever upper half of the byte characters that the selected code page allows.

Comment: This is right answer,
INSERT dbo.Test (TestValue) VALUES ('ક્ષત્રીય જ્ઞાન'); //You will get ??? in db column
INSERT dbo.Test (TestValue) VALUES (N'ક્ષત્રીય જ્ઞાન'); // work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you can take column datatype Nvarchar and then you can insert in Gujarati